# Android Studio can't authenticate with SVN

Tags: android, svn, intellij-idea, tortoisesvn, android-studio

I'm new in Android Studio. I'm trying to import my project and work with the built-in svn of android studio.

When I import the project to android studio, it works fine but the svn of android studio can't authenticate when I update, commit...

The authentication dialog re-appears repeatedly.

What I did:

1. Import project folder from svn server using **TortoiseSVN**
2. Import project to eclipse and export it as **Gradle** (Because project on
   SVN is eclipse project)
3. Import that gradle project into **Android Studio**

My SVN server is 'svn+ssh' connect. When I'm trying to update or commit, Android studio can't authenticate.

Error:

```
svn: E204899: E170012: When using svn+ssh:// URLs, keep in mind that the --username and --password options are ignored because authentication is performed by SSH, not Subversion
svn: E170012: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://zuranai.arx-project.com/opt/SVN1.zap_dev/trunk/android'
svn: E170012: Can't create tunnel
svn: E720002: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

### What's wrong with my android studio? Any advice?

Edited:
I can't commit, update but still can revert.

[image]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had same problem, but found a solution.

1. Go to 'Android Studio > Preferences > Version Control > Subversion'
2. Uncheck  follow two items

   - Use command line client
   - Use system default Subversion configuration directory

It will now work correctly.

Comment: For me the path was Android Studio > Settings > Version Control > Subversion.

Comment: For me it was File -> Settings ->VersionControl-> SubVersion in Android Studio

Answer (score 4):

I also have this problem.
Here is how i solve it:
On the "File" menu,click "Invalidate Cashes/Restart..."

then,the problem solved!

Comment: I had to combine Daniel Lee's solution and yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look on issue reported in Intellij Idea with some workarounds in reply if it helps you

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-26844  (Srinivas Reply)

and

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81294 (Irina Chernushina (JetBrains))

> you need to set your configuration info in SVN tunnel config
>   file(~/.subversion/config) kssh = /your/path/to/ssh
>
> in tunnel section.example mine looks like : kssh = /usr/bin/ssh
>
> Remember you need to point your IDE to use subversion config file in
>   the subversion options or change it in ~/.subversion_IDEA/config file

Comment: sorry for late reply. I've found 'config' file. But I don't know what is '/your/path/to/ssh'. Where can I get It?

Comment: @Dolphin quite busy, path to the directory where your private key is stored for authentication . If you were using eclipse with ssh earlier yo can find the path in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an other solution : in my case, the SVN SSL certificate is a self-signed, so AndroidStudio won't make checkout until the certificate is accepted. It seems that AndroidStudio doesn't ask what the user want to do.

The solution was to make a checkout with tortoiseSVN (do it with svn command line otherwise) in a temporary folder. Tortoise asked you for accepting the certificate : choose 'Permanently accept'. After that, AndroidStudio checked out successfully my files.

Please note that AndroidStudio might be configured to use the system svn environment (File > Settings > Version Control > Subversion).

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion -> Click on Clear Auth Cache
Step 2: Again check out the project by freshly giving the user credential details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to apply any of the above solutions with AS Chipmunk 2021.2.1.

It looks like AS just fails to create an SVN repository.

This was on Linux, so I just created it from the system command line:

```
svnadmin create my_repository_name
```

After that, I was able to proceed with importing the project into the repository.

Answer (score 0):

for Android Studio Electric Eel version
tested on mac os only [setting in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Jvb.png)
make sure that svn is configured(~/.subversion/config) in terminal  and ssh key file is mentioned

[tunnels]

ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -i /path-to-ssh-file/

go to android preference->version control -->Subversion -->Enbale interactive mode