# Subversion not authenticating when using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Android Studio can't authenticate with SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323421/android-studio-cant-authenticate-with-svn)

I got an Android project which I used in Eclipse and I just converted it to a working AS project. When using Eclipse, the SVN works fine. When using AS for some reason, every time I try to commit or update, I get a prompt asking for my user name and password and it keeps repeating itself without ever succeeding. When I press cancel I get this error:

> Error:svn: E170012: When using svn+ssh:// URLs, keep in mind that the --username and --password options are ignored because authentication is performed by SSH, not Subversion
>
> svn: E170012: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://...
>
> svn: E170012: Can't create tunnel
>
> svn: E720002: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.

What I tried until now was Uncheck follow two items

```
Use command line client
Use system default Subversion configuration directory
```

Also, I tried editing the servers file in the SVN config's folder with:

```
store-passwords = yes
store-ssl-client-cert-pp = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = yes
store-ssl-client-cert-pp-plaintext =yes
```

What else can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just checking out the project again to a new folder even without setting all the things I wrote in the question and everything started working